On quiver mutations arrows
I was reading introduction to cluster algebras and I had a question regarding quiver mutations, I know the steps sequence, so that I don't understand the following, if I make the mutation on vertex $2$ then why in $\mu_{2}(Q)$ is there an arrow $12 \rightarrow 13$. One thing to consider is that vertices $1, 12, 123, 234, 34, 4$ are frozen. 
